# Streaming from ArrayList returns null error if no match

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

I have a button which when clicked, loops through an `ArrayList<User>` and tries to match the `emailText` text to the object `getEmail()`.

```
btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    User declaredUser = App.getUsers().stream()
        .filter(o -> o.getEmail().equalsIgnoreCase(emailText.getText())).findFirst().get());
```

It works fine when the email does exist and `.get()` returns the `declaredUser`. However, when there is no match, I receive this error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present

I have tried adding `!= null` like so:

```
User declaredUser;
if ((declaredUser = App.getUsers().stream()
        .filter(o -> o.getEmail().equalsIgnoreCase(emailText.getText())).findFirst().get()) != null) {
    // Code here ...
}
```

However, I still receive this error. Can anyone point me in the right direction to first checking `findFirst()` returns a value? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've seen, `Optional#get` throws a `NoSuchElementException` if the `Optional<T>` is empty; I wouldn't recommend calling it at all for this reason, especially since you don't know whether the `Optional<T>` is empty or not.

Because `Stream#findFirst` returns an `Optional<T>`, you can use `Optional#ifPresent` to only continue execution if the `Optional<T>` is **not** empty:

```
App.getUsers()
   .stream()
   .filter(o -> o.getEmail().equalsIgnoreCase(emailText.getText()))
   .findFirst()
   .ifPresent(declaredUser -> {
        // declaredUser is in scope here!
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob, that solved my problem! I'll accept the answer when I can, I really appreciate the explanation too!